# Unknown column data type when creating table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I need to create a MySQL table with following columns:

*id-------order_id-------service_id -------service_info*

but I don't know what type of data will be stored in ***service_info*** column. It could be date, time-range, email or phone number. How do I go about that? Should I just give it varchar?

Comment: string usually is the safest way to go. Everything you provided can easily be serialized/deserialized to/from a string.

Comment: Yes, you should use text if you don't know the exact type.  _However_, a better approach might be to somehow separate the date, phone, etc. information into separate columns, and then use a more specific data type for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer in this case you would better use varchar type ,

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  It is just information for a human to read:  `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`

Case 2:  Structured data, but you are unlikely to need to search/sort on the pieces:  Consider JSON.

Case 3:  You are likely to search/sort:  Make separate column(s) for email or phone, etc so that they can be indexed.  There may still be more stuff that falls into case 2.  Example: "Beware of duck in back yard".